# What's the grammatical role of "mille passus" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, accusative, case

In chapter XII of the 2003 edition of *Lingua latina per se illustrata*, one can read the following sentence (lines 93-94):

> Aemilius in castrīs habitat mīlle passūs ā fīne imperīi.

I understand its meaning, but I can't figure out the grammatical role of "mīlle passūs". Since "habito" is a transitive verb, should "mīlle passūs" be interpreted as the direct object for such verb? I.e., is "passus" in accusative plural case?

Comment: Adverbial accusative is used for measuring length

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian: But I would say this is distance.

Answer (score 7):

*Mille passus a fine imperii* is an adverbial phrase modifying *habitat*. *Habitat* is used intransitively in this sentence. *Mille passus* is in the accusative because that's generally the case used to denote length or extent. [Allen and Greenough 425](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/extent-space) cites for example Caesar:

> fossās quīndecim pedēs lātās (B. G. 7.72)
> trenches fifteen feet broad

Comment: For my question, a relevant piece of information in your source is: "Distance when considered as extent of space is put in the accusative" (it's below the excerpt you have reported). The example given, also from Caesar *B. G* ("Mīlia passuum tria ab eōrum castrīs castra pōnit"), is somewhat confusing because of the presence of the word "mīlia", which is [always accompanied by a plural genitive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1989/). But I suppose "tria" should be interpreted as accusative plural neuter. Anyway, for completeness, can you please add this to your answer?

Comment: [Here](https://www.culturaclasica.com/lingualatina/valores.de.los.casos.pdf) one can find a good explanation in Spanish (section 3.4).